# sf::Sprite is white rectangular (texture trying to pass by reference)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference, sfml

This is **resources.h:**

```
extern sf::Sprite Sprite00;

void load_sprite(sf::Sprite &externalSprite, sf::Texture &externalTexture) ;
void draw_sprite(sf::RenderWindow &window, sf::Sprite &externalSprite);
void setposition_sprite(sf::Sprite &externalSprite, float x, float y);
```

This is **resources.cpp**:

```
sf::Sprite Sprite00;


void load_sprite(sf::Sprite &externalSprite, sf::Texture &externalTexture)
{
    externalSprite.setTexture(externalTexture);
}
void draw_sprite(sf::RenderWindow &window, sf::Sprite &externalSprite)
{
    window.draw(externalSprite);
}
void setposition_sprite(sf::Sprite &externalSprite, float x, float y)
{
    externalSprite.setPosition(x, y);
}

void loadResources()
{
    sf::Texture myTexture;
    myTexture.loadFromFile("images/block3d.png");

    load_sprite(Sprite00, myTexture);
}
```

In **game.cpp**:

```
void Game::render()
{
    window.clear(); 

    setposition_sprite(Sprite00, 100, 100);
    draw_sprite(window, Sprite00);

    window.display();
}
```

The sprite that is displayed is white rectangular, texture is lost. I don't know how to fix it. I'm not passing reference correctly I guess.

loadResources is called in main.cpp. I want to display this Sprite00 for example in game.cpp in function Game::render();. Also if I want to display it somewhere else in another cpp what should I do to make it right?

Comment: "loadResources is called in main.cpp" Code or it didn't happen. Better , construct a [mcve] and post it if constructing the MVCE didn't leave you groaning and feeling silly.

Answer (score 2):

`sf::Sprite` stores a pointer to the texture you give it. But in your `loadResources` function, you are creating a local `sf::Texture` object, and applying that to your sprite. When the function returns, the texture is destroyed, and your sprite is left holding a dangling pointer. You need to make sure lifetime of the texture at least encompasses the duration of your use of the sprite.

Note that the description for the `sf::Sprite` class in [the documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Sprite.php) has a paragraph warning against precisely what you are doing:

> It is important to note that the sf::Sprite instance doesn't copy the
>   texture that it uses, it only keeps a reference to it. Thus, a
>   sf::Texture must not be destroyed while it is used by a sf::Sprite
>   (i.e. never write a function that uses a local sf::Texture instance
>   for creating a sprite).

Comment: So, how can I use this sprite with this texture in another file?

Comment: @Sadin97: I don't understand what you're asking. Please elaborate.

Comment: Basicly I understand what are you talking about. My question is how can I pass that texture to another file (for example if I define sf::Sprite and sf::Texture in one file (resources.cpp/resources.h) and want to use it in other file (for example game.cpp) how can I pass them correctly? How can I use that local texture in other file, how should I define that texture, on what place should I define it and how to use it somewhere else? I am trying to make separate file for defining and loading textures/sprites and another separate file to use them. How?

Comment: @Sadin97: You're already using a sprite defined in one file (`Sprite00`, declared in `resources.h` and defined in `resources.cpp`) in another file (the `Game::render()` function in `game.cpp`). So you could just declare and define your texture in the same way, and the same place as you do your sprite.

Comment: I can't use the texture the same way I use sprite as external variable because: "Some SFML resources can't be declared in the global scope. They do internal stuff during their construction and destruction, which involves other global variables that may not be available due to non-deterministic order of initialization of globals."